# Error: The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: json, flutter, dart, error-handling, flutter-layout

I want to use index in this code but giving me error in the code

```
Error: The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
        user.index,
             ^
```

Code

```
final index = Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Text(
    user.index,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.black),
  ),
);
```

Declarations are as follows

```
class User {
      final int index;
      final String about;
      final String name;
      final String email;
      final String picture;
      User(this.index, this.about, this.name, this.email, this.picture);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send a integer to a parameter of type String so basically you just need to cast the integer to a string using the toString method.

You can look at the documentation at [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/int/toString.html) if you have any doubts.

```
final index = Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Text('${user.index}'),
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.black),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Then you should mark the question as solved giving this answer a tick.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @Josep Bové's answer, Effective Dart documentation says using String interpolation is more preferable. Source, [prefer-using-interpolation-to-compose-strings-and-values](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#prefer-using-interpolation-to-compose-strings-and-values). So you could do `Text('${user.index}')`